# Motion sensor to flash a 12v light

Tags: outdoor, light, motion-sensor

I'm looking for a way to put a motion sensor at the end of the driveway and wire it about 150' up the driveway to a 12v light.

The operation I'm looking for, is when the sensor sees a car I want the light to blink for about 30 seconds and then shut off until the next car.

Comment: wired or wireless? cars only? what about trucks? bicycles? pedestrians? dogs?

Comment: I think having the sensor wired to the light would be most reliable. And just vehicles in general. Not too picky if people set it off.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Do you mean literally "blink" - like on 1 second, off 1 second, repeating for 30 seconds? Or do you mean "30 seconds = blink" - i.e., on for 30 seconds and then off?

Comment: Like 1 second on and 1 second off. For 30 or so seconds.

Comment: It may be reimagining your project but I’d google ‘driveway detector’.  You’re not the first person with the need, and there are options better than ‘motion’ which is problematic outside.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a problem and easy to do in 12V. Not only are 12V motion sensors readily available, they are about half the cost of 120V ones!

I do not recommend running lamp power 150' at 12V.  I would have the 150' run be signal only (and power for the sensor[s]) and have a relay or electronic module operate the lamp proper.  The reason is voltage drop at that distance. A mere annoyance at 120V, it is critical at 12V.

Voltage drop is proportional to actual current flowed, so keep that bare minimum on the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Google driveway alert.  There are packages on the shelf.  Good Luck.